# APScheduler doesn't fire the job after waking up from system sleep

Tags: python, nohup, apscheduler

I wrote a simple python script scheduled to send me a message once every month. I run the script script on my macbook which is mostly in sleep mode during the day (I never shut down my laptop). 
However, it didn't execute the job when I woke my laptop up after the time for the job has passed (of course, the duration is within the period of my misfire_grace_time as I deliberately set the misfire_grace_time to be particularly long enough to cover a 1-month sleep).

Here is my script:

```
# Define function to check internet connection
try:
    import httplib
except:
    import http.client as httplib

def have_internet():
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com", timeout=5)
    try:
        conn.request("HEAD", "/")
        conn.close()
        return True
    except:
        conn.close()
        return False
# =============================================================================
# songline is a module for sending a message to my mobile phone via "LINE application" 

import songline
token = '.......this is my API token.......'
messenger = songline.Sendline(token)
msg = 'Checked'

# =============================================================================
import time

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
sched = BackgroundScheduler()

def job_check():
        if(have_internet()):
            messenger.sendtext(msg)
        else:
            time.sleep(60)
            job_check()            


sched.add_job(job_check, trigger = "cron", day = 1, hour = 20, misfire_grace_time=2592000)

sched.start()


while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

I ran this python script by using command line:

```
nohup python /path/to/script.py &
```

Thank you in advance for all suggestions! I'm very new to python scripting and APScheduler.

Comment: Have you read the troubleshooting instructions in the documentation?

Comment: It's possible that `time.sleep()` may not work as expected when the machine is put to sleep, but I have not checked this yet. Might be a good first step in debugging this.

Comment: @Alex Yes, I have read the documentation but couldn't find any solution on this. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem. That is happens because next_wakeup_time is not updated in db when PC sleeping.

First what i did it caught the problem like this:

```
def enshure_scheduled_jobs(scheduler, logger:logging.Logger):
    dt_now = datetime.now(tz=get_localzone())
    jobstore = 'default'
    missed_jobs = [] 
    for j for j in scheduler.get_jobs(jobstore=jobstore):
        if ( dt_now - j.next_run_time ).total_seconds() > j.misfire_grace_time :
            missed_job.append(j)
            logger.warning(f'Found missed job {j.id} [{j.next_run_time}] < now is:[{dt_now}]')
```

...

```
scheduler.start()  
while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        missed_jobs = enshure_scheduled_jobs(scheduler, logger)
```

And after that i think all is need is reschedule job by calling `scheduler.reschedule_job()` [apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.reschedule_job](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.reschedule_job).

Or something to recalc next_job_time

```
    scheduler.pause_job(j.id)
    scheduler.resume_job(j.id)
```

Comment: I think calling `scheduler.wakeup()` is sufficient to make the scheduler refresh the next execution time after system sleep.